# Firebase ionic iOS ERROR -[FIRApp isDataCollectionDefaultEnabled]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ionic-framework

When I try to run a ionic project in Xcode I have a ERROR:
`Thread 1: Exception: "-[FIRApp isDataCollectionDefaultEnabled]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002c859e0"`

My pods in config.xml:

```
        <pod name="GoogleSignIn" version="4.4.0" />
        <pod name="GoogleAppUtilities" />
        <pod name="GoogleAuthUtilities" />
        <pod name="GoogleUtilities" />
        <pod name="Firebase/Auth" />
        <pod name="Firebase/Analytics" version="4.2.0" />
        <pod name="Firebase/Core" />
        <pod name="Firebase/Performance" />
        <pod name="Firebase/RemoteConfig" />
        <pod name="FBSDKCoreKit" version="5.8.0" />
        <pod name="FBSDKLoginKit" version="5.8.0" />
        <pod name="FBSDKShareKit" version="5.8.0" />
```

My package.json which related to IOS:

```
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "6.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cleartext": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "^1.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^4.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication": "^3.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-photo-library-sism": "^2.2.97",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.1",
```

What I tried to do:

- Create folder 'Resource' with GoogleService-Info.plist in 'platforms/iOS/Resource' file;
- Change in File->Workspace settings->Build system from 'New Build System' to 'Legacy Build System';
- Run such commands: `pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all` and `pod install`;
- I fixed all warnings with pods ( added `$(inherited)` )
- Tried to remove all versions in pods. See **Podfile.lock**

I cannot figure out what happening. Please help me.

### Podfile.lock

```
  - FBSDKCoreKit (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (= 5.8.0)
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (= 5.8.0)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (5.8.0)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics
  - FBSDKLoginKit (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKLoginKit/Login (= 5.8.0)
  - FBSDKLoginKit/Login (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
  - FBSDKShareKit (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKShareKit/Share (= 5.8.0)
  - FBSDKShareKit/Share (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
  - Firebase/Analytics (4.2.0):
    - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Auth (4.2.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseAuth (= 4.2.0)
  - Firebase/Core (4.2.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.0.3)
    - FirebaseCore (= 4.0.7)
  - Firebase/Performance (4.2.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebasePerformance (= 1.0.5)
  - Firebase/RemoteConfig (4.2.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseRemoteConfig (= 2.0.3)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.3):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseAuth (4.2.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseCore (4.0.7):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.10):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
  - FirebasePerformance (1.0.5):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - FirebaseRemoteConfig (2.0.3):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - GoogleAppUtilities (1.1.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleAuthUtilities (2.0.2):
    - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleSignIn (4.4.0):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (~> 2.1)"
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (2.2.2):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.2.2)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (2.2.2):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.2.2)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (2.2.2)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (= 2.2.2)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.2.2)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (= 2.2.2)"
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (2.2.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities (6.7.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (= 6.7.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (= 6.7.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/ISASwizzler (= 6.7.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (= 6.7.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (= 6.7.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (= 6.7.1)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (= 6.7.1)"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (= 6.7.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/SwizzlerTestHelpers (= 6.7.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (= 6.7.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.7.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.7.1):
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/ISASwizzler (6.7.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.7.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (6.7.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.7.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.7.1)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.7.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/SwizzlerTestHelpers (6.7.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (6.7.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.4.0)
  - nanopb (0.3.9011):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.9011)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.9011)
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.9)
  - Protobuf (3.12.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `version="4.2.0"`.

That version of Firebase is more than three years old. If you really want the old version to work, you may need to examine the Podfile.lock and restrict some other pods to old versions as well.

Comment: I have the same error, I removed all versions. I added my Podfile.lock to the question.

Comment: The Podfile.lock is still showing version 4.2 for Firebase. The current version is 6.30. Maybe run `pod update`?